# What type of equation has a differential equation as its solution?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

In basic algebra, the solutions to equations are numbers. For differential equations, the solutions are families of functions. What type of equation has a differential equation as its solution?

Comment: Let's start with a simpler question: what equation has _the equation $x^2-1=0$_ as a solution?

Comment: It's hard to specify a "type". You could have $\left(\dfrac{dy}{dx}-x\right)\left(\dfrac{dy}{dx}-1\right)=0$, or $\left(\dfrac{dy}{dx}-x\right)\left(\dfrac{dy}{dx}+x\right)=0$. You could say that the solutions of these equations are differential equations, but the solutions are ultimately functions that satisfy those differential equations, not the equations themselves (unless you willingly treat differential equations as acceptable solutions, in which case solving the equations will no longer be necessary).

Comment: Or maybe something which produces a *family of* differential equations (so you can say they are the solution, rather than get one and solve it)

Comment: How about something with hideous terms like $\frac{d^xy}{dz^x}$ in it, where $x$ is a variable?

Comment: ^ That would work.

Comment: Or, say, $f^{(an)}(x)+f^{(bn)}(x)=g(x)$ with $n$ left as a variable?

Comment: Newton's brain.

Comment: How about the Euler-Lagrange equation?